# (error_10) Please enter a valid data value (Must be hex.)MyEther Wallet

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, myetherwallet, cpp-ethereum

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to deploy a smart contract on Myteherwallet but getting an error while deploying the byte code of the smart contract which is written in solidity remix IDE.

[image]

I have even tried to change the object byte code starting with "0x+ByteCode"but still facing same problem

I have copied the following byte code from remix here is an screenshot and then pasted in MyEther wallet deploy contract option

[image]

Here is that bytecode which is obtained from remix.
What changes do I have to do before pasting into myetherwallet ?

```
{
    "linkReferences": {},
    "object":"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",
    "opcodes": "PUSH1 0x80 PUSH1 0x40 MSTORE PUSH1 0x0 DUP1 SSTORE CALLVALUE DUP1 ISZERO PUSH2 0x14 JUMPI PUSH1 0x0 DUP1 REVERT JUMPDEST POP PUSH2 0x17E DUP1 PUSH2 0x24 PUSH1 0x0 CODECOPY PUSH1 0x0 RETURN STOP PUSH1 0x80 PUSH1 0x40 MSTORE PUSH1 0x4 CALLDATASIZE LT PUSH2 0x57 JUMPI PUSH1 0x0 CALLDATALOAD PUSH29 0x100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 SWAP1 DIV PUSH4 0xFFFFFFFF AND DUP1 PUSH4 0x3E21F396 EQ PUSH2 0x5C JUMPI DUP1 PUSH4 0x830FB67C EQ PUSH2 0xA7 JUMPI DUP1 PUSH4 0xD3507D71 EQ PUSH2 0xF2 JUMPI JUMPDEST PUSH1 0x0 DUP1 REVERT JUMPDEST CALLVALUE DUP1 ISZERO PUSH2 0x68 JUMPI PUSH1 0x0 DUP1 REVERT JUMPDEST POP PUSH2 0x91 PUSH1 0x4 DUP1 CALLDATASIZE SUB DUP2 ADD SWAP1 DUP1 DUP1 CALLDATALOAD SWAP1 PUSH1 0x20 ADD SWAP1 SWAP3 SWAP2 SWAP1 DUP1 CALLDATALOAD SWAP1 PUSH1 0x20 ADD SWAP1 SWAP3 SWAP2 SWAP1 POP POP POP PUSH2 0x11D JUMP JUMPDEST PUSH1 0x40 MLOAD DUP1 DUP3 DUP2 MSTORE PUSH1 0x20 ADD SWAP2 POP POP PUSH1 0x40 MLOAD DUP1 SWAP2 SUB SWAP1 RETURN JUMPDEST CALLVALUE DUP1 ISZERO PUSH2 0xB3 JUMPI PUSH1 0x0 DUP1 REVERT JUMPDEST POP PUSH2 0xDC PUSH1 0x4 DUP1 CALLDATASIZE SUB DUP2 ADD SWAP1 DUP1 DUP1 CALLDATALOAD SWAP1 PUSH1 0x20 ADD SWAP1 SWAP3 SWAP2 SWAP1 DUP1 CALLDATALOAD SWAP1 PUSH1 0x20 ADD SWAP1 SWAP3 SWAP2 SWAP1 POP POP POP PUSH2 0x133 JUMP JUMPDEST PUSH1 0x40 MLOAD DUP1 DUP3 DUP2 MSTORE PUSH1 0x20 ADD SWAP2 POP POP PUSH1 0x40 MLOAD DUP1 SWAP2 SUB SWAP1 RETURN JUMPDEST CALLVALUE DUP1 ISZERO PUSH2 0xFE JUMPI PUSH1 0x0 DUP1 REVERT JUMPDEST POP PUSH2 0x107 PUSH2 0x149 JUMP JUMPDEST PUSH1 0x40 MLOAD DUP1 DUP3 DUP2 MSTORE PUSH1 0x20 ADD SWAP2 POP POP PUSH1 0x40 MLOAD DUP1 SWAP2 SUB SWAP1 RETURN JUMPDEST PUSH1 0x0 DUP2 DUP4 SUB PUSH1 0x0 DUP2 SWAP1 SSTORE POP PUSH1 0x0 SLOAD SWAP1 POP SWAP3 SWAP2 POP POP JUMP JUMPDEST PUSH1 0x0 DUP2 DUP4 ADD PUSH1 0x0 DUP2 SWAP1 SSTORE POP PUSH1 0x0 SLOAD SWAP1 POP SWAP3 SWAP2 POP POP JUMP JUMPDEST PUSH1 0x0 DUP1 SLOAD SWAP1 POP SWAP1 JUMP STOP LOG1 PUSH6 0x627A7A723058 KECCAK256 0xc2 ADDMOD 0x29 0xee 0xb6 0xc8 PUSH1 0x88 SHR EXTCODESIZE 0xd1 EQ 0xdc 0xee DUP8 0xea 0xe4 PUSH27 0x4B3AE6B9A29B6432033D3A28B60E00290000000000000000000000 ",
    "sourceMap": "27:399:0:-;;;74:1;50:25;;27:399;8:9:-1;5:2;;;30:1;27;20:12;5:2;27:399:0;;;;;;;"
}
```

After taking object string part for hex value ,error is not generating but next step is also not showing which should be of signed transaction

Comment: And where supposed to guess all the details relevant to this operation (your input, to begin with)???

Comment: Well, the error message tells you that this is an invalid bytecode. And it is! What you've entered here is a list of assembly opcodes (your disassembled contract I would presume?). The bytecode is an hex string which should be available to you in the output `bin` file that your compiler has generated for you.

Comment: I have copied the byte code from remix ide after compilation of my solidity code and then pasted in MyEther wallet deploy contract option

Comment: Get read of the `"object":` part, and then from the `"` at the beginning and end of the remaining string.

Comment: Did not get you

Comment: The second image that you've posted shows that you have pasted the string `"object": "..."`. Get rid of everything except the `...`.

Comment: please refer new edit

Comment: What's so hard to get??? Just the long hexadecimal string (the one mapped to the `object` field)!

Comment: just did ! now no output is showing

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy directly from Remix with MetaMask. Go to the "Deploy & Run Transactions" tab, set the Environment to "Injected Web3" to use MetaMask, and deploy your contract there. Make sure you're connected to the right network in MetaMask when doing so.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The solution is super simple. Right now your bytecode is like

```
{
"object" : "ff133..............."
"opcodes" : "................."
}
```

what you really need is ff133............... (string corresponding to the bytecode) so what solved my problem was to copy this string (the one which looks like ff133............... in my example) (without double quotes) and paste it in the bytecode (after clearing the bytecode you entered earlier)